# Accept Delegate Custom Workflow activity

Tags: development, workflow-activity

I am currently building a custom workflow activity for Visual Studio 2010.

I would like to create a method invoking property, like many of the ootb activities have:

```
        public static DependencyProperty WebNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("WebName", typeof(string), typeof(ListIteratorActivity));

    [Category("Cross-Site Actions"), Browsable(true)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility
      (DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public string WebName
    {
        get
        {
            return Convert.ToString(base.GetValue(FirstNameProperty));
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(FirstNameProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Above is an example of a method accepting a string, how do I make a property to accept a method?

**UPDATE**

When I try

```
        public static DependencyProperty MethodInvokingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MethodInvoking", typeof(Delegate), typeof(ListIteratorActivity));

    [Category("Cross-Site Actions"), Browsable(true)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility
      (DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public Delegate MethodInvoking
    {
        get
        {
            return (Delegate)base.GetValue(MethodInvokingProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(MethodInvokingProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

it throws an error of

> Error 1   Could not create activity of type
>   'HumanResources.ListIteratorActivity'. System.ArgumentException: Type
>   'HumanResources.ListIteratorActivity' does not define a static
>   dependency event with name 'MethodInvokingEvent'. Parameter name:
>   ownerType    at
>   System.Workflow.ComponentModel.DependencyProperty.ValidateAndRegister(String
>   name, Type propertyType, Type ownerType, PropertyMetadata
>   defaultMetadata, Type validatorType, Boolean isRegistered)    at
>   System.Workflow.ComponentModel.DependencyProperty.Register(String
>   name, Type propertyType, Type ownerType)    at
>   HumanResources.ListIteratorActivity..cctor()  C:\Users\sebastiens\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2010\Projects\Quarphix\HumanResources  1   1

Comment: Ever found a way?

Comment: dont think so sorry, but if you find one please post it here :)